# SDL2 understanding the basic model

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

**SDL** I don't get the basic model or structure that sdl presents, by that I mean the basic elements in SDL library.
I don't get when to use surface, when texture and when render.

Comment: I believe a Surface is a image stored on the system RAM for when you use software rendering, a Texture is a texture on the GPU for accelerated rendering.

Comment: You don't show any source code in your question, so it is probably off-topic here. Did you consider asking on some SDL specific forum or mailing list?

Comment: I didn't find any article or video that would ans my question, so i asked it here expexting a detailed ans from an expert!

Comment: You can have a look at my tutorial :
http://headerphile.com/sdl2/sdl2-part-2-your-first-sdl2-application It should answer your questions. And if not ; feel free to comment

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `SDL` and `SDL2` is that the `Surface` API has been largely replaced with the `Render` API. The rule of thumb is to use `Surface` when you need to do software pixel manipulation, and use `Render` when you need to draw lots of stuff to the screen really fast.

For example it would be reasonable to load an image into a `SDL_Surface`, combine it with some text originating in a second surface, and then convert the composite image to a `SDL_Texture` that is rendered to the screen every frame.

If you want to draw to the screen, use the `Render` API.